# Saving array of loaded images as a csv

Tags: python

I am working on an image classification task. I use opencv to load the images. Most of them are very huge in size so I resize them as well.

I wanted to know if there is a way to save the loaded images e.g (1000, 227,227,3) as a csv or something else?

So that I don’t have to load all the images on every run of my python code.

Thanks

Comment: How is `1000, 227, 227, 3` an image?

Comment: Hi, I could have written it more clearly. So, (1000, 227, 227, 3) would be a numpy array of 1000 images, size 227 x 227 and 3 channels i.e rgb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use "pickle" to save a list-object of image objects.

```py
import pickle
# to safe
myImagesList = [...]
with open("myImages.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(myImagesList, file)

# to load it again
with open("myImages.pickle", "rb") as file:
    mySavedImagesList = pickle.load(file)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!